# JavaScript Command document.getElementsByClassName not working on special page

Tags: javascript, python, qwebengineview, angular2-ngcontent

I am currently writing a bot to fetch data from a web live ticker. Therefore i created an app, that displays the webbrowser using Python QWebEngineView.
Now if i want to get a special Value from the html code of the site i am currenty using:

```
self.browser.page().runJavaScript(
            "document.getElementsByClassName('team-score')",
            self.__update_points
        )
```

(browser is the QEngineWebView). The HTML of the site looks as following: (only the interesting snippet)

```
<div _ngcontent-jnr-c126="" class="set-scores">
        <div _ngcontent-jnr-c126="" class="team-score">2</div>
        :
        <div _ngcontent-jnr-c126="" class="team-score">2</div>
</div>
```

My goal is to extract the two point values ( `class="set-score"`), but when i run the JS command it only throws out `{}` where should be those two objects.

Comment: I haven't worked with the python library, but it's probably a timing problem.Try wrapping the statement with `setTimeout` for testing.

Comment: Try: `[...document.getElementsByClassName('team-score')].map(el => el.innerText)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an HTMLCollection Object. It's iterable so it can easily be converted to an array with the spread operator.

As mentioned in my comment, try `[...document.getElementsByClassName('team-score')].map(el => el.innerText)`.

The reason why it just returns an empty object is that the `JSON.stringify()` return value of [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) is just `{}` and you can't pass references in several situations while using tools like QWebEngineView. The object in the this will be passed to `JSON.stringify()` and sent to the extension/worker or whatever, therefor you might end with an useless result.

Converting it to an Array with `[...HTMLCollection]` and mapping it afterwards with the innerText of the value will result in `[2,2]`.

Another solution would be: `document.querySelector(".set-scores").textContent` (or innerText) which may result in a string like `"2:2"`.

Comment: the way u suggested worked thank you